# why is gcc gets executed in this make file?

Tags: makefile

I have the following makefile when type make i got the following output. why is gcc gets called in this case?

```
nasm -felf ./source/multiboot.s
gcc   multiboot.o   -o multiboot
gcc: error: multiboot.o: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [multiboot] Error 4
```

makefile:

```
CC=gcc
ASM=nasm
ASMFLAG=-felf
SOURCE=./source/

all: multiboot

multiboot.o: $(SOURCE)multiboot.s
    $(ASM) $(ASMFLAG) $(SOURCE)multiboot.s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "all" command depends on "multiboot", but there is no explicit rule defining how to produce "multiboot". In this case, Make uses a predefined rule that understands that, if the "$target.o" target exists, then "$target" can be constructed from "$target.o" by running the linker (in this case, GCC).

It seems like the problem in this case is that your instructions for the "multiboot.o" command does not actually produce the file "multiboot.o" as output. Try simply doing:

```
 multiboot.o: multiboot.s
```

(That is, without specifying the command to run). Simply declaring this dependency should, by a similar mechanism, result in an implicit rule/command to create the "multiboot.o" output from "multiboot.s".